# SQL - pick current date from machine and compare the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2014

**Scenario 1: Current Year**

Always code needs to pick

> The last Sunday of January for the current year. For ex(31-01-2016)

*Current code - picks 1st of Jan 2016*

```
convert(date,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

**Scenario 2: Last Year**

Always code needs to pick

> The last Sunday of January for the Previous year. For ex(01-02-2015)

*Current code - picks 1st of Jan 2015*

```
convert(date,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, dateadd(YEAR, - 1, getdate())), 0))
```

Instead of hard coding the date. I would like to pick date from machine and compare.

**Week start from Sunday and ends Saturday**. Any help please?

Comment: @dan Apologies, I have updated the question

Comment: This may help, I don't have time to test it though: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/735e9bfd-dc8f-4023-8177-827e0b87576e/function-for-last-sunday-of-the-month?forum=transactsql

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using? There are different ways of doing this in newer versions of sql server.

Comment: @sean-lange I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I am not really sure what you are expecting for output here. Do you want the last sunday of the current month or the last sunday of the year? Or maybe it is the last Sunday of January for the current year? Or is it the last sunday of january next year?

Comment: @sean-lange I am looking for " The last Sunday of January for the current year"

Comment: @dan - Thanks for the link. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please see answer in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003806/sql-server-date-automate

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sample Demonstrative Data/Test Results
Declare @YourTable table (SomeDate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values  ('2000-06-15'),('2001-06-15'),('2002-06-15'),('2003-06-15'),('2004-06-15'),('2005-06-15'),('2006-06-15')
,('2007-06-15'),('2008-06-15'),('2009-06-15'),('2011-06-15'),('2012-06-15'),('2013-06-15'),('2014-06-15'),('2015-06-15'),('2016-06-15')
,('2017-06-15'),('2018-06-15'),('2019-06-15'),('2020-06-15')

-- To Confirm Results
Select Year           = year(SomeDate)
      ,LastSundayDate = DateAdd(DD,-DatePart(DW,DateFromParts(Year(SomeDate),12,31))+1,DateFromParts(Year(SomeDate),12,31))
      ,LastSundayName = DateName(DW,DateAdd(DD,-DatePart(DW,DateFromParts(Year(SomeDate),12,31))+1,DateFromParts(Year(SomeDate),12,31)))
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Year    LastSundayDate  LastSundayName
2000    2000-12-31      Sunday
2001    2001-12-30      Sunday
2002    2002-12-29      Sunday
2003    2003-12-28      Sunday
2004    2004-12-26      Sunday
2005    2005-12-25      Sunday
2006    2006-12-31      Sunday
2007    2007-12-30      Sunday
2008    2008-12-28      Sunday
2009    2009-12-27      Sunday
2011    2011-12-25      Sunday
2012    2012-12-30      Sunday
2013    2013-12-29      Sunday
2014    2014-12-28      Sunday
2015    2015-12-27      Sunday
2016    2016-12-25      Sunday
2017    2017-12-31      Sunday
2018    2018-12-30      Sunday
2019    2019-12-29      Sunday
2020    2020-12-27      Sunday
```