# SQL Server : date automate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario 1**: current year

Always SQL code needs to pick  **The last Sunday of January for the current year.** For ex(31-01-2016)

Below SQL code gives answer for above question

```
select case when DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))) = 1
        then DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, Convert(date, GetDate())))
        else DateAdd(d, -DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, GetDate()))) + 1, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate()))))
    end
```

**Scenario 2**: last year

Always code needs to pick **The last Sunday of January for the Previous year**. For ex(01-02-2015)

What will be the SQL code Scenario 2 Please?

Week start on Sunday and ends on Saturday.

Comment: uhm.......what?

Comment: Posting the question again doesn't help clarify the exact same question you previously asked....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001280/sql-pick-current-date-from-machine-and-compare-the-year

Comment: what happens if we flag this as a duplicate of that one, and flag that one as a duplicate of this one.  Does the universe survive?

Comment: @marc-s,@scsimon,@kritner,@habo,@lamak I have updated my question. I hope its clear now. Can you please remove "On Hold"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way, using the `day of week` option (`w`) for `DatePart`:

```
declare @StartDate date = GetDate()
declare @FirstDayofYear date = DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @StartDate) + 1, @StartDate)
declare @LastDayOfJanuary date = DateAdd(d, 30, @FirstDayofYear)

select case When DatePart(w, @LastDayofJanuary) = 1
        Then @LastDayofJanuary
        Else DateAdd(d, -DatePart(w, @LastDayOfJanuary) + 1, @LastDayOfJanuary)
    end
```

Obviously, you can change `@StartDate` to whatever date you want, including this date last year:

```
declare @StartDate date = DateAdd(yy, -1, GetDate())
```

Or, if you want it all expanded into a single expression, here it is with `GetDate()`:

```
 select case when DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))) = 1
        then DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, Convert(date, GetDate())))
        else DateAdd(d, -DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, GetDate()))) + 1, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate()))))
    end
```

Note that this assumes that your machine is set with the week starting on Sunday.  You might have to tweak this if you week starts on another day, because day 1 will be a different date.

**Edited to add:**  The formula above will return the last day in January, or the Sunday previous to the last day in January if the last day isn't a Sunday.

But the OP's definition of the last Sunday in January can go into February, based on the example given in the question.  Here's a better formula for that situation:

```
declare @StartDate date = GetDate()
declare @FirstDayofYear date = DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @StartDate) + 1, @StartDate)
declare @LastDayOfJanuary date = DateAdd(d, 30, @FirstDayofYear)

select case When DatePart(w, @LastDayofJanuary) = 1
    Then @LastDayofJanuary
    Else DateAdd(d, 7 - DatePart(w, @LastDayOfJanuary) + 1, @LastDayOfJanuary)
end
```

The expanded version would be:

```
select case When DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, GetDate()))) = 1
    Then DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))
    Else DateAdd(
                d, 
                7 - DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, GetDate()))) + 1, 
                DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))
                )
end
```

**TO CONVERT THIS TO RETURN THE PRIOR YEAR'S VALUE**

Replace all instances of `GetDate()` with `DateAdd(yy, -1, GetDate())`.

Comment: Excellent the single expression worked for scenario 1 (in my question). Any idea foe scenario 2(in my question) please?

Comment: Excellent the single expression worked for scenario 1 (in my question). Any idea for scenario 2(in my question) please?

Comment: I have edited my question to include a different formula, that will work better in your situation (last Sunday in January can be after 31 January).  I have also added instructions for generating a version for the prior year.

Comment: Excellent. Worked. Many Thanks

Comment: The above qury gives wrong result, If I run the above query it gives,

Example 1 : Picks wrong date

Assume Current Date is - '2017-01-01'
SQL picks below dates,
Between '2017-02-05' and '2016-12-31'

('Picks Start of the Next Year' and 'Last day (Saturday) of previous week')
Example 2 : Picks correct date

Assume Current Date is - '2017-02-12'
SQL picks below dates,
Between '2017-02-05' and '2017-02-11'

('Picks Start of the Next Year' and 'Last day (Saturday) of previous week')
The problem is always January Month.
How to fix Example 1 please? Any updated SQL Query?

Comment: I have asked the question in detail, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442208/sql-server-date-automate-tsql-query