# SQL Server : date automate TSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I want SQL query to get the dates automatically,

Please Note: year should always start on the **Last Sunday of January**.

I want a SQL query for below example; assume current date is '2017-01-01'

SQL should pick these dates:

```
Between '2016-01-31' and '2016-12-31'
```

(between 'Start of the Year (Last Sunday of January Month)' and 'Last day (Saturday) of previous week')

I have this query:

```
Between 
    case 
       When DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, GetDate()))) = 1
          Then DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))
          Else DateAdd(d, 7 - DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, GetDate()))) + 1, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GetDate()) + 1, convert(date, GetDate())))
                )
       end
and 
    convert(date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5)
```

The above query is returning wrong results:

**Example 1**: **Wrong**

Assume current date is '2017-01-01', the SQL query returns these dates:

```
Between '2017-02-05' and '2016-12-31'
```

which are wrong.

**Example 2**: **Correct**

Assume current date is '2017-02-12', then the SQL query returns these dates:

```
Between '2017-02-05' and '2017-02-11'
```

which are the correct dates - OK.

> The problem is always when the current date is in January

**How to fix example 1 please**? Any updated SQL query?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running? If at least 2012, the [EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) function will probably be of use to you!

Comment: @bridge, SQL Server 2014

Comment: You mentioned year should always start on the 1st February, then how you will get 'Between '2016-01-31' and '2016-12-31'' for '2017-01-01', i think it should be 'Between '2016-02-07' and '2016-12-31'

Answer (score 1):

If Feb of any year is your fixed parameter then you compare the current date to it and based on the result use it or not:

```
    DECLARE @GetMyDate datetime = '2017-01-01'--GETDATE()

    SELECT  @GetMyDate,
            CASE 
                WHEN    @GetMyDate < DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(@GetMyDate))) + '-02-01'))
                THEN    DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(@GetMyDate)-1)) + '-02-01'))
                ELSE    DateAdd(d, 7 - DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @GetMyDate) + 1, @GetMyDate))) + 1, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @GetMyDate) + 1, convert(date, @GetMyDate))))
            END AS StartDate,
            convert(date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, @GetMyDate) - 1, 0) + 5)  AS EndDate
```

Update:

```
BETWEEN CASE 
            WHEN    GETDATE() <= DATEADD(Day,-0,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(GETDATE()))) + '-02-01'))
            THEN    DATEADD(Day,-0,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(GETDATE())-1)) + '-02-01'))
            ELSE    DateAdd(d, 7 - DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()))) + 1, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, GETDATE()) + 1, convert(date, GETDATE()))))
        END 
        AND
        CASE 
            WHEN    GETDATE() = DATEADD(Day,-0,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(GETDATE()))) + '-02-01'))
            THEN    DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(GETDATE()))) + '-02-01'))
            ELSE    Convert(date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) + 5)
        END
```

Comment: I am not sure if you actually had the following in mind: Between '2016-12-31' and  '2017-01-31'

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to enter the Current date manually. It wants to be picked on its own.

Comment: Replace the variable with getdate()

Comment: year start date - 'XXXX-02-01' and Year end date - 'XXXX-01-31'

Comment: where XXXX is the same year for both instances?

Comment: From:
For Year 2016 – year start date - '2016-02-01'. 
Again for Year 2017– year start date - '2017-02-01'.
To:
End date should be - Last day (Saturday) of previous week'

Comment: excellent thanks. I have one more requirement please.  What will be the query if we want "getdate () = Last Year Current date".

Comment: Please elaborate on the question: What do you want to achieve with that? How will it fit into the context of the query?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look. Your help will be very helpful.

Comment: Use a combination of the initial answer and the updated answer. For last years date you'll have to pass a parameter or use dateadd(year,-1,getdate()), etc.

Comment: I used this query, but I am not getting right answer. `DECLARE @GetMyDate datetime = '2018-01-21'`

Comment: `SELECT  @GetMyDate,
            CASE 
                WHEN    @GetMyDate < DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(@GetMyDate))) + '-02-01'))
                THEN    DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), (year(@GetMyDate)-1)) + '-02-01'))
                ELSE    DateAdd(
                d, 
                 - DatePart(w, DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @GetMyDate) + 1, @GetMyDate))) + 1, 
                DateAdd(d, 30, DATEADD(y, - DatePart(y, @GetMyDate) + 1, convert(date, @GetMyDate)))
                )`
           END AS SD

Comment: `convert(date, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, @GetMyDate) - 1, 0) + 5)  AS EndDate`

Comment: For the above query Start date and End date working fine for Year 2017. But for 2018 Start date (January Month) is Wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132395/discussion-between-danie-schoeman-and-user2331670).

Comment: Chat room is closed. I have a question how can I ask you please?

Comment: Add a comments again.